# unityでConfine Screen Edgesが出てこない

Tags: unity3d

Unity、およびプログラミング初心者です。
カメラがキャラクターを一定の範囲で追跡するようにしたいと思っています。
「Unity入門」というサイトでは、
CM vcam1についているChinemachine Virtual CameraのAdd Extensionをクリックし、Chinemachine Cofinerを追加すると「Confine Screen Edges」という名前のチェックボックスが出ると記載されています。
しかし、私のPC上ではこのチェックボックスが出て来ません。Chinemachine Cofinerを追加するところまでは出来ています。
どうすればConfine Screen Edgesを出すことが出来るでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 念のため使用しているUnityのバージョンと、参考にしているサイトのURLも記載があると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

私も同じサイトを見て全く同じ状況でしたが、Main CameraのProjectionってところをPerspectiveからOrthographicに切り替えたらConfine Screen Edges出てきました！